# How to add scroll bar for sidebarPanel in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have to add more sliders in sidebarPanel but when i scroll the page down,
the entire page scrolls down along with mainPanel. What exactly i need is, mainPanel where the graph or output is displayed has to be locked or freezed in such a way when i scroll down the input slider and change the slider to observe the corresponding output on the mainPanel in Shiny.

Below is the part of the code of ui.R. Here I have shown only 7 sliders but actually I have 31 sliders.

```
library(shiny)  
shinyServer(fluidPage(  
  titlePanel("Regression"),  
  sidebarLayout(    
    sidebarPanel(   
      sliderInput("slide1","Select a value:",
                  min=min(unidf$X.17,na.rm = T),max=max(unidf$X.17,na.rm = T), value = median(unidf$X.17,na.rm = T)),  
      sliderInput("slide2","Head HIC-15:",
                  min=min(unidf$X.18,na.rm = T),max=max(unidf$X.18,na.rm = T), value = median(unidf$X.18,na.rm = T)),  
      sliderInput("slide3","Select a value:",
                  min=min(unidf$X.19,na.rm = T),max=max(unidf$X.19,na.rm = T), value = median(unidf$X.19,na.rm = T)),  
      sliderInput("slide4","Select a value:",
                  min=min(unidf$X.20,na.rm = T),max=max(unidf$X.20,na.rm = T), value = median(unidf$X.20,na.rm = T)),  
      sliderInput("slide5","Lateral force (kN):",
                  min=min(unidf$X.21,na.rm = T),max=max(unidf$X.21,na.rm = T), value = median(unidf$X.21,na.rm = T)),  
      sliderInput("slide6","Select a value:",
                  min=min(unidf$X.22,na.rm = T),max=max(unidf$X.22,na.rm = T), value = median(unidf$X.22,na.rm = T)),  
      sliderInput("slide7","Average deflection (mm):",
                  min=min(unidf$X.23,na.rm = T),max=max(unidf$X.23,na.rm = T), value = median(unidf$X.23,na.rm = T))  

    ),  
    mainPanel(...
```

Comment: Good question but strange for me. In my cases I needed to fix a sidebar and a header panel because in a main panel is where I have many objects. Anyway it is a good practice to try that all controls could be visible without scrolling. You could put some of them into a main panel, for example

Answer (score 3):

I had similar situation. Here is my solution:

```
dashboardSidebar(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                      .sidebar { height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto; }
                      " )
      )
    ),
... ...
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Please look at the code which I have updated and help me manipulating the code according to your solution.

Answer (score -2):

I indeed find @cutebunny 's answer to work on dashboardSideBar:

```
library(shiny)

################################ interactive datatable + functional scrollbar
library(shinydashboard)
## ui.R ##
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "TEST"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        # to add scrollbar
        tags$head(
            tags$style(HTML("
                      .sidebar { height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto; }
                      " )
            )
        ),
        # to fill sideBar
        p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), 
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("See data", tabName = "db")
        ),
        radioButtons("rb1", label = "Select data",
                     choices = list("IRIS" = "iris", "CARS" = "cars"),
                     selected = "iris")
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(tabName = "db",
                    h4("Show selected dataset"),
                    fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl2'))
            )
        )
    )
)
## server.R ##
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$value <- renderPrint({ input$rb1 })
    data <- reactive({
        switch(input$rb1,
               "iris" = iris,
               cars)
    })
    action <- dataTableAjax(session, cars)
    widget <- datatable(cars,
                        class = 'display cell-border compact',
                        filter = 'top',
                        # server = TRUE,
                        options = list(ajax = list(url = action))
    )
    output$tbl2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(data())
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, when using `sidebarLayout()`, `tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".sidebar { height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto; }")))` did not work for me, so I used `style = "height:80vh; overflow-y: auto;"` instead:

```
################################ interactive datatable + functional scrollbar
library(shinydashboard)
## ui.R ##
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("TEST"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        style = "height:90vh; overflow-y: auto;",
            # to fill sideBar
            p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), p("text"), 
            sidebarMenu(
                menuItem("See data", tabName = "db")
            ),
            radioButtons("rb1", label = "Select data",
                         choices = list("IRIS" = "iris", "CARS" = "cars"),
                         selected = "iris")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            DT::dataTableOutput('tbl2')
        )
    )
)
## server.R ##
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$value <- renderPrint({ input$rb1 })
    data <- reactive({
        switch(input$rb1,
               "iris" = iris,
               cars)
    })
    action <- dataTableAjax(session, cars)
    widget <- datatable(cars,
                        class = 'display cell-border compact',
                        filter = 'top',
                        # server = TRUE,
                        options = list(ajax = list(url = action))
    )
    output$tbl2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(data())
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Keep in mind that if I remove `style = "height:80vh; overflow-y: auto;",` from the code above, a scrollbar for the whole window is created instead.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for proposing an answer. Since the difference between your solution and cutebunny is very small. If I understand correctly cutebunny suggests `90vh` and you `80vh` I'd recommend to add your feedback as a comment and verify that the difference is not due to your screen resolution of your browser.

Comment: Hi, changing 90vh to 80vh does not change anything substantially for me, I changed this value in my answer in order to make it less confusing. In the first block of code, I merely used cutebunny's answer and did not add anything to it. I intended to provide a template of this useful answer for people to easily use it.
In the second block of code, I intend to provide a solution that works for `sidebarLayout()`, which is (to me) more generic than `dashboardSideBar()`.
Also, I did not test this using a web browser, but the shiny default interface.